# How to load dataset in a batch for ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a large data in to table and i want to populate it remotely,
when i start to fetch data, after some time connection get lost, and the  action ends,

pls help me to over come..!!

regards,
Akhil

Comment: is "don't pull so much data" a viable option? it should be pretty rare that you need to shift large volumes of data around...

Comment: Use [BeginLoadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata.aspx) and [EndLoadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.endloaddata.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off looking at using an ETL Tool.  If you are using sql server, ssis may be an option.
I've used Rhino ETL in the past to good success - http://ayende.com/blog/3102/rhino-etl-2-0

You can also search this forum or google for ETL Tools.  That should give you various options.

hope that helps....

Comment: Thanks, but is there any easy way..? because we are using Enterprise lib 5.0 to communicate with database and I found that some queries loads huge data( may a customer or product)

Comment: the scenario is i m fetching the product data from DB to fill product combo.this is huge

Comment: I would still recommend looking at ETL tools.  ETL (Extract-Transform-Load) tools are generally used when working with larger amounts of data.